# Keep me signed in sample

Tags: codenameone

is there a sample of how to implement "keep me signed in" feature in codename one? I'm guessing it involves the encrypted storage feature and maybe something else you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [storage encryption](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/seamless-storage-encryption.html) if you want but generally if you just want to keep a username/password combination you can just do:

```
Preferences.set("username", myUserName);
```

Then later on in the code:

```
if(Preferences.get("username") != null) {
    // use the username from preferences
}
```

Comment: Is it secure to store password in Preferences? Shouldn't I use something like ios keychain?

Comment: That's why I provided the link to storage encryption which will make it more secure. Apple's keychain is unique to Apple and isn't available on other OS's so we don't expose similar functionality.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. 1.) user signs in and selects keep me singned in 2.) I will encrypt the storage with password 3.) app is closed completely 4.) user opens the app, he should be signed in (as keep me signed in is active), how I get the password, when the storage is encrypted with the password, which I don't know and can't ask the user, as he should be kept signed in?

Comment: Encrypt the storage with your own app specific key. The problem with using the password to encrypt the storage is that the password might change...  Alternatively you can have two preferences locations but that includes some juggling.